# How can I extract a specific item attribute from an ebay listing using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
def get_data(url):
  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  return soup

current_data = get_data(link)
x = current_data.find_all(text="Style Code:")
```

I'm trying to get the style code of a shoe off ebay but the problem is that it doesn't have a specific class or any kind of unique identifier so I can't just use find() to get the data. Currently I searched by text to find 'Style Code:' but how can I get to the next div? An example of a shoe product page would be [this.](https://www.ebay.com/itm/295319451862?epid=5052193901&hash=item44c26938d6%3Ag%3AdaoAAOSwgzxjEOX9&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAoEMZK%2BAt53WWy7KwuyWFgYOxBl3QiPjE4CvliMZHtIrWxjXKkweXW3BEssmmSLXA71DcNcn2Iwuqw%2FsNbjK%2B%2F5aF3tI2I7MLD0UmVoRivcuKztAMEtexAROaUYy4wxo5n1HxO8HnswPaZb55q1Nau1tQRnAplrOCB2jDeiLDawK2BaZJqiUnNbOOqulNUXqD9y591w%2FrgTJEiOEUxBMYvnI%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7adraGJYQ&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1000)

Answer (score 2):

```
soup.select_one('span.ux-textspans:-soup-contains("Style Code:")').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'ux-textspans'})
style_code = None
for idx, span in enumerate(spans):
    if span.text == 'Style Code:':
        style_code = spans[idx+1].text
        break
print(style_code)
# 554724-371
```

Since there are lot's of span is similar (with class `'ux-textspans'`) you need to iterate through it and find the next span after `'Style Code:'`

Comment: you don't need this big round at all!, just do `soup.select_one('span.ux-textspans:-soup-contains("Style Code:")').find_next('span').get_text(strip=True)`